Error in the graphical interface and wifiError in the graphical interface and wifi
While installing these packages :libapr1t64 libaprutil1t64 libglib2.0-0t64 liboss4-salsa-asound2 libxcb-cursor0 my computer rebooted and the GUI and WiFi were removed.
